# Rails / Webpack: TinyMCE cannot load skins (404 (Not Found))

Tags: ruby-on-rails, npm, webpack, tinymce

I am working on a Rails project that has been using assets pipeline but we are currently trying to transition to webpack. I encountered a problem when attempting to get TinyMCE to work after pulling it through yarn - the text editor simply won't load.

### Before the transition to webpack

Originally I used a CDN in the **application.html.haml** and things were working fine:

```
%script{src: 'https://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.min.js?apiKey=gexncjni90zx3qf0m5rr7kl8l40wd5yuly2xjza0g3kwrljt'}`
```

---

### After the transition

I installed the package through yarn:
`$ yarn add tinymce`

I also have my **tinyMce.js** file (the function itself has not been changed):

```
import tinymce from 'tinymce/tinymce';
import 'tinymce/themes/modern/theme';
import 'tinymce/plugins/lists';
import 'tinymce/plugins/table';

function tinyMce() {
    $(document).on('turbolinks:load', function () {
        tinyMCE.remove();
        tinyMCE.init({
            selector: 'textarea.tinymce',
            plugins: [
                'table', 'lists'
            ],
        });
    });
}

export { tinyMce };
```

---

And in my **application.js**:

```
import { tinyMce } from "../vendor/tinyMCE/tinyMce";
```

Since TinyMCE will not work without a skin, I followed the [documentation](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/usage-with-module-loaders/) and ran

`$ cp -r node_modules/tinymce/skins skins`

But the error in the console does not get resolved:
[image]

I tried putting the `skins` folder directly in the root directory, in a `packs` folder placed in the root and in the `javascript/packs` but the error stays the same, even when I try specifying the `skin_url`.

### General notes

- Webpack itself is working fine, both with custom scripts and imported packs (tested with `typed.js`).
- `tinymce` seems to be loading as well - previously I had more errors in the console, regarding the `table` and `lists` plugins, but these went away after adding the 2 import lines to `tinyMce.js`.

Any tips on what I might be missing?

Comment: I'm curious why you had to switch from the CDN.  Would the cloud script not still work to deliver the editor?

Comment: Also, when you use skin_url what is the path you are using.

Comment: @RobQuan The point of switching from the CDN is keeping things cohesive and since we're starting to use webpack, ideally all external libraries would be pull from there. I now got it to work (see answer below), but despite things working fine, I'm getting an error in the console.

Answer (score 6):

I managed to get it to work by adding these 2 lines to my **tinyMce.js** file:

```
import 'tinymce/skins/lightgray/content.min.css';
import 'tinymce/skins/lightgray/skin.min.css';
```

At that point the text editor was working as expected, however I was getting the following errors in my console:

[image]

This was resolved by adding `skin: false` to my `tinymce.init`setup.